# Swift Sprite Kit Errors

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, swift, xcode6

I made a new Swift Sprite Kit Xcode 6 project, and even 2 errors popped up when I first ran it. They were:

```
ld: can't open -sectcreate file: /Users/Comrod/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/gametest-bmmegykevoxrgrdcemlwvbflbtab/Build/Intermediates/gametest.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/gametest.build/Objects-normal/i386/gametest.swiftmodule
```

and

```
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What's confusing me is that I made the same project but with Objective-C as the main language, and there were no errors. What exactly is the issue here, and how can I resolve it?

Comment: Do not forget that Swift/Xcode6 are betas and therefore really unstable... ;) Do no hesitate to report bugs to Apple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I run into the same issue when project name contained character "'", so, maybe check the naming.